# Giving different ID's to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

So, I have a function in which I loop 10 times, to create 10  elements. What I'm trying to accomplish is: I want to give those `div` Elements Different `id`s so I can reach them separately when needed.

```
function addDay() {  
    for(k = 0; k < 10; k++){
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.background = "red"
        div.style.color = "white"
        div.style.width = "40px"
        div.style.height = "20px"
        div.style.margin = "0.5px"
        div.style.textAlign = "center"
        div.style.borderRadius = "6px"
        div.setAttribute("class", "studentGrades");
        div.setAttribute("id", "sgId")

        div.setAttribute("onclick", "averageFunc(this, Number(prompt('Please, enter number here')))");

        div.innerHTML = "0"

        document.querySelector("#container3").appendChild(div)
    }
}
```

So I'd like to get something similar to this,

- First div = `div id="sgId1"`
- Second div = `div id="sgId2"`
- Third div = `div id="sgId3"`, etc.

Note: I'm just starting with coding itself, currently into the 3rd week of vanilla JS. So I can't use any Library/Frameworks

Comment: Just use the variable `k` i.e.  `.setAttribute("id", "sgId" + (k+1))`

Answer (score 0):

Use the k value in the loop for specify each element.

```
div.setAttribute("id","sgId"+k);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression:

```
div.id = "sgId" + (k + 1);
```

### Demo

```js
var total = 0;
var c101 = document.querySelector("#class101");
var gradeAvg = document.querySelector("#gradeAvg");
var list = document.createElement("ol");

for (let k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.classList.add("grade");
  li.id = "sgId" + (k + 1);
  li.textContent = "0";
  li.addEventListener('click', enterGrade);
  list.appendChild(li);
}

c101.appendChild(list);

function enterGrade(e) {
  var num = Number(prompt(`Please, enter number here`));
  e.target.textContent = num;
  var total = avg(num);
  gradeAvg.textContent = total;
}

function avg(num) {
  var sum = total += num;
  return sum / 10;
}
```

```css
.grade {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0.5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Student Grades</h4>
<section id='class101'></section>
<label>Grade Average: </label><output id='gradeAvg'></output>
```